# removeFromArray function with rest parameters works in Firefox console, but fails test in npm

Tags: javascript

I am doing The Odin Project JavaScript exercises and have been struggling with exercise 4 for over a week.

This is my function:

```js
const removeFromArray = function (...args) {
    let normalArray = args;
    normalArray.splice(2, 1);
    return normalArray;

}

removeFromArray(1, 2, 3, 4)

returns [1, 2, 4]
```

The exercise test expects it toEqual to [1, 2, 4]. That is exactly what I get when I run the code in Firefox.

When I run the code in Visual Studio Code through npm, the test fails.

Comment: "*When I run the code in Visual Studio Code through npm, the test fails.*" what is the message you get when that happens?

Comment: ```js 
removeFromArray
    ✕ removes a single value (6 ms)
    ○ skipped removes multiple values
    ○ skipped ignores non present values
    ○ skipped ignores non present values, but still works
    ○ skipped can remove all values
    ○ skipped works with strings
    ○ skipped only removes same type

  ● removeFromArray › removes a single value

    expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

    - Expected  - 0
    + Received  + 4

      Array [
    +   Array [
          1,
          2,
    +     3,
          4,
    +   ],
    +   3,
      ]
```